# Ionic 4 with Angular: Any Upgrade Guidelines available?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, upgrade

I would like to **upgrade my Ionic Framework based Angular** App to Angular 8.x.

1. Is there an official guideline for upgrading Ionic Apps?
2. Does the ionic CLI support developers during the upgrade process (like angular cli)?
3. Does the ionic framwork support [ng update](https://angular.io/cli/update)?

**Current Version:**

The output below was generated by `ionic info` (executed in the project folder):

*Ionic:*

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.1 (C:\ProgramData\nvm\v10.15.0\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.9.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.8
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1
```

*Cordova:*

```
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.0.1, (and 8 other plugins)
```

*Utility:*

```
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 0.2.8
```

*System:*

```
   NodeJS : v10.15.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ionic 4 & Angular 8 Forum and Updating Ionic to Angular 8 (Google Docs) finally supported me during the update process to Angular 8. https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-angular-8/167535 
 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QOpQeDifPSg6F9WycDLcbQnpqjN96ew-Ap0_CB7CcCQ/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the semi-official guide (posted by Mike Hartington from the Ionic team) to upgrading Ionic 4 to Angular 8:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QOpQeDifPSg6F9WycDLcbQnpqjN96ew-Ap0_CB7CcCQ

I just tried it and it works like a charm.

> ### Updating Ionic to Angular 8
>
> **Update @ionic/angular and @ionic/angular-toolkit to the latest release**
>
> ```
> npm install @ionic/angular@4.7.0
> npm install @ionic/angular-toolkit@2.0.0 -D
> ```
>
> From here we can run the following commands
>
> ```
> npx ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
> ```
>
> **Now most packages should be updated, just to be sure, we also need to update these**
>
> **Install the latest angular devkit updates with**
>
> ```
> npm i @angular-devkit/architect@latest @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest @angular-devkit/core@latest @angular-devkit/schematics@latest
> ```
>
> Or if you’re on a mac/linux
>
> ```
> npm i @angular-devkit/{architect,build-angular,core,schematics}@latest
> ```
>
> **Potential Issues**
>   There is a known bug in an older version of the Angular CLI that will cause the update commands to stop running and
>   exit. If you encounter this, please look over this issue and use the
>   commands below.
>
> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14589
>
> ```
> npx ng update @angular/core
> npx ng update --allow-dirty @angular/core --from 7 --to --migrate-only
>
> ng update @angular/cli --allow-dirty
> ng update @angular/cli --allow-dirty --from 7 --to 8 --migrate-only
> ```
>
> There is a known bug where the Angular CLI will attempt to install
>   Angular 8.2.0-next. If you encounter this, please look over this issue
>   and use the commands below:
>
> https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14980
>
> ```
> npm install @angular/cli@latest
> npx ng update @angular/core
> ```
>
> Notice that this has you updating the Angular CLI first, then updating
>   Angular Core. From here, you can continue on with the remaining
>   commands in the guide above.
>
> If you encounter any problems, please open a new issue on the Ionic
>   repo with detailed steps to reproduce:
>   https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues